# play mp3 audiofile

Tags: c#, .net, audio, mp3

I have written some code for playing a `.wav` through my application. Now I want to play a mp3 file through.

I have .NET framework 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have .NET framework 1.1. only, probably your best approach is to use a P/Invoke wrapper for mciSendCommand

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
private static extern long mciSendString(
        string strCommand, StringBuilder returnString, 
        int returnBufferLength, IntPtr callback);

void PlayFile(string mp3FileName)
{
    string deviceType = "MPEGVideo";
    string fileName = mp3FileName;
    string alias = "MyMp3File";
    string playCommand = string.Format("open \"{0}\" type {1} alias {2}",
                            fileName, deviceType, alias);
    mciSendString(playCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    playCommand = string.Format("play {0} from 0", alias);
    mciSendString(playCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    // send these when you are finished
    // playCommand = "stop MyMp3File";
    // playCommand = "close MyMp3File";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/). Otherwise you may consider to use a native library using Interop.

Comment: NAudio is compiled against 2.0, although you may find you can recompile the bits you need against 1.1. There are simpler ways (such as sending MCI string) if you simply need to be able to start and stop.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using DirectShow - the RenderFile API is extremely simple.  [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshownet.aspx) site appears to show a managed wrapper for DShow (caveat programmer, I've not used it).

Edit to add:  Personally I'd stay away from the MCI APIs if at all possible - they're extremely old APIs and they're not particularly reliable.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't use mci APIs myself. But though the RenderFile API call itself is simple, the sheer amount of COM interfaces that have to have .NET wrappers created before you can get started is daunting for most developers, especially if all you want to do is play an MP3 File. Still the link to the managed wrapper looks like it would be very helpful. +1 from me.